Redirect to localhost on localmachine instead of redirecting on same server
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return redirect('http://localhost:5002/login')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)

I am running 2 container applications on same host using azure container group, after successful deployment I am able to  access the application using http://public-ip:5001, but when I click on login link it redirect me to http://localhost:5002/login. but the problem is localhost is pointing to my local machine, but I want it to redirect to localhost:5003 on server. so that I am redirected to sidecar container.

I don't think you can use localhost here.  In a redirect context, that will be interpreted as "the machine running the browser", not "the machine running the containers", "the application container", or "the login service container" (all of which separately believe they themselves are localhost).

You can probably use the public ip in the redirect statement instead of localhost.
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return redirect('http://<public-ip>:5002/login')

